# "Any" lambda operator for $filter parameter on MS Graph and REST People API Calls

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, o365rwsclient

I'm attempting to use the 'any' lambda operator to retrieve a list of Person objects based off of the relvanceScore or rank properties of the EmailAddresses and scoredEmailAddresses collections, respectively:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$filter=scoredEmailAddresses/any(s:s/relevanceScore ge 5)
```

or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/people?$filter=emailAddresses/any(s:s/rank ge 5)
```

or

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/people?$filter=EmailAddresses/any(e:e/Rank ge 5)
```

---

I get either an HTTP 504 or HTTP 503 when running any of these three queries against the Beta and v1.0 Graph endpoints, as well as the O365 REST Beta endpoint. This behavior occurs when using the /users/{user-id} syntax as well.

Does anyone get back a successful result when attempting these queries?

Answer (score 0):

According to the state from [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter),

> The any lambda operator is supported for some APIs.

Based on my test, the endpoint `/me/people?$filter=emailAddresses/any` current is not support. So I suggest you to submit an feature request on [the user voice](https://office365.uservoice.com/)